# Matplotlib: Fit plot with labels into subplot area

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I want to make a plot with a grid of thumbnails on the left and a line plot on the right. Here is a minimal example

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

### This can change at runtime
n_grid = 4

### Grid of thumbnails
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10.2))
for i in range(n_grid):
    for j in range(n_grid):
        ax = plt.subplot2grid(shape=(n_grid, 2*n_grid), loc=(i,j))
        plt.imshow(np.random.random((16,16)))
        ax.set_axis_off()

### Line plot
ax = plt.subplot2grid(shape=(n_grid, 2*n_grid), loc=(0,n_grid), rowspan=n_grid-1, colspan=n_grid)
plt.plot(np.cumsum(np.random.random(100)), label='Random Sum')
plt.xlim([0, 100])
plt.ylim(0,50)
plt.xlabel('Number', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('Sum', fontsize=12)

plt.figtext(0.5, 0.01, f'Unique identifier', ha='center', va='baseline')

#plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.01, bottom=0.03, right=0.99, top=0.99, wspace = 0.06, hspace=0.06)
plt.savefig('plot_1.png', dpi=96)
```

[image]

The problem is that the yticklabels and ylabel stick over the center into the area of the thumbnails. The lineplot on the right is too wide.

One common solution found on the internet is using automatic resizing with tight_layout(), so I change the last three lines to

```
plt.tight_layout()
#plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.01, bottom=0.03, right=0.99, top=0.99, wspace = 0.06, hspace=0.06)
plt.savefig('plot_2.png', dpi=96)
```

[image]

This does not rescale the lineplot, but instead makes the wspace and hspace attributes so big I get way too much whitespace between the thumbnails.

I am looking for a solution to either

- Set wspace and hspace of only the right subplot, not all of them together, or
- resize the lineplot to fit into the designated area, without the labels sticking out

It would seem that this is an easy problem, but despite searching for about 2 hours and digging around in the object properties with iPython I found nothing suitable. All solutions seem to change the size and padding of the subplots, not fitting a plot into the area defined with `subplot2grid`. The only other solution I can think of is a hack that calculates a modified `aspect` from the value ranges to make the lineplot always a given percentage thinner.

Answer (score 1):

You can play around with [`subfigures`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subfigures.html). For example, if you do:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


### This can change at runtime
n_grid = 4

### Grid of thumbnails
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10.2))

# add 2 subfigures
subfigs = fig.subfigures(1, 2, wspace=0)

# add thumbnail grid into left subfig
gsLeft = subfigs[0].add_gridspec(n_grid, n_grid)

axLeft = []
for i in range(n_grid):
    for j in range(n_grid):
        axLeft.append(subfigs[0].add_subplot(gsLeft[i, j]))
        axLeft[-1].imshow(np.random.random((16,16)))
        axLeft[-1].set_axis_off()

### Line plot
gsRight = subfigs[1].add_gridspec(3, 1)
axRight = subfigs[1].add_subplot(gsRight[:2, 0])

axRight.plot(np.cumsum(np.random.random(100)), label='Random Sum')
axRight.set_xlim([0, 100])
axRight.set_ylim(0,50)
axRight.set_xlabel('Number', fontsize=12)
axRight.set_ylabel('Sum', fontsize=12)

# adjust subfigures here (play around with these to get the desired effect)
subfigs[0].subplots_adjust(wspace=0.03, hspace=0.03, bottom=0.05, top=0.95, left=0.05, right=0.95)
subfigs[1].subplots_adjust(left=0.01)

# add title (here I've had to add it to the left figure, so it's not centred,
# in my test adding it to the figure itself meant it was not visible, although
# the example in the Matplotlib docs suggests it should work!) 
# fig.suptitle(f'Unique identifier', x=0.5, y=0.025, ha='center', va='baseline')
subfigs[0].suptitle(f'Unique identifier', x=0.5, y=0.025, ha='center', va='baseline')

fig.savefig("plot_1.png", dpi=150)
```

This gives:

[image]

but you can play around with the values to adjust it as you like.